# Swift 4 - How to display in UIAlert an error response from JSON Alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, uialertcontroller

I am stuck with I am sure a stupid stuff.

I would like to display an error if I received one from the API.

In the exemple bellow I have 2 errors so I would like to display 2 lines in my Alert message.

This is what I receive from Alamofire:

```
let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!):
▿ {
  "errors" : {
    "tva" : [
      "Tax must be numeric."
    ],
    "data_id" : [
      "Data id must exist"
    ]
  },
  "message" : "The given data was invalid."
}
  - rawArray : 0 elements
  ▿ rawDictionary : 2 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : "errors"
      ▿ value : 2 elements
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          - key : "tva"
          ▿ value : 1 element
            - 0 : Tax must be numeric.
        ▿ 1 : 2 elements
          - key : "data_id"
          ▿ value : 1 element
            - 0 : Data id must exist
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : "message"
      - value : The given data was invalid.
  - rawString : ""
  - rawNumber : 0
  - rawNull : <null>
  - rawBool : false
  - type : SwiftyJSON.Type.dictionary
  - error : nil
```

This is what i tried:

```
SharedClass.sharedInstance.alertTitle(view: self, title: "Error".localized, message: "\(swiftyJsonVar["errors"].description)")
```

But it display this:

```
"{\n  \"errors\" : {\n    \"tva\" : [\n      \"Tax must be numeric.\"\n    ],\n    \"data_id\" : [\n      \"Data id must exist\"\n    ]\n  },\n  \"message\" : \"The given data was invalid.\"\n}"
```

I would like to have something lie this in this cases It should be displayed on 2 lines:

```
tva: Tax must be numeric.
data_id: Data id must exist
```

So it will display n lines depending on the number of error received.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Show your code for getting the response.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're specifying Swift 4 when 5.0 has been available for over a year and the current version is 5.2?

Comment: description is for debugging, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Errors is a dictionary ... you need to access it using keys

```
for key in errors.keys {

            if let val = errors[key] {
            errorString = errorString + "\(key):\(val)\n"
            }

        }

        print(errorString)
```

Comment: Tks jawadAli that was the way to do it.

Comment: let me know if you face any issues